# Accidentally removing gnome

Tags: boot, gnome, login

I accidentally removed my gnome desktop using the terminal, and my computer is single booted, what can I do to restore  I can’t even login to Ubuntu
tty1….
I tried all the solution that was given previously but none works… sorry if am repeating the same quiz

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: *"I can’t even login to Ubuntu tty1"* please try to be more descriptive - does the `login:` prompt not show? have you forgotten your username? your password? does your login attempt fail, and if so, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't know how to use `chroot` to access your broken system:

   Since you cannot login, use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to preserve your data.
   Then use the same LiveUSB to reinstall.
2. If you do know how to use `chroot`:

   Use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.
   Chroot into the broken system.
   Repair.